# How long device will keep data if It does not come online

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, persistence, offline, offline-mode

I like the idea of [Firestore persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

If a write is done on Flutter Application to a Collection, but application has no internet access. I understand that it will be written to firestore when device comes back online.

My question is, what about if device comes online after 30 days or 1 year. The document says **temporary network interruptions** , how much temporary ?

Does the write ever gets aborted ? Suppose  device comes online after 2 years, will it write the pending data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the write ever gets aborted?

No.  Not until the device or app storage is cleared for whatever reason.

> Suppose device comes online after 2 years, will it write the pending data?

Yes.